# Which network site for FDA software compliance questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which network site should I use for FDA software compliance questions?
I was thinking maybe Stack Overflow but it seems like kind of a gray area to me.  I'm not planning on relying on answers from the Internet for making important legal decisions, I'm merely planning to ask questions about where I can find relevant online documentation about FDA, GDPR, etc.  Does anyone know which network would be most appropriate for software questions that relate to legal compliance for healthcare, privacy, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legal questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow (and most other programming sites in the network). I would have a look at [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/); they have [some questions about software already](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) even though not all of them are about *development*.

> I'm not planning on relying on answers from the Internet for making important legal decisions

Great idea; that's the standard disclaimer for this site:

> Law Stack Exchange is for [educational purposes only](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer) and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner. Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

As always, [search](https://law.stackexchange.com/search) if your question hasn't been asked before, and check the Help Center articles [What topics can I ask about here?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) if you phrase it carefully I would suggest using the [clinical-trials] tag as well as any relevant software tag and stating clearly what searches you have already made. I cannot guarantee it will not be closed as too broad or opinion based but that is the risk you take.